# How to debug a Zend\Form?

Tags: validation, debugging, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-validate

In a project I have a huge form -- with many fields, nested fieldsets, collections etc. The form validation is failing and I don't know, why.

How should such a problem be handled? **What is a good, efficient approach to find out, why a form validation is failing?**

Comment: after `isValid` you can fetch the errors using  `$form->getMessages()`.

Comment: you can also use a debugger like xdebug

Comment: @AlexP I'm not sure, that it always helps. E.g. in my case: I've debugged the [`Zend\Form#isValid()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/Form.php#L523) class at the place, when the validation is completed and was expecting the messages. But `Order\Form\OrderForm#messages` was empty. The `$result` is `false` and the `$messages` is empty.

Comment: @Unex Yes, of course, I'm debugging with Xdebug. The question was more about, what to looking for, in order to make the debugging fast.

Comment: @automatix Provided you have called it after `isValid()`, you should always get an error. If you're debugging, I would start with the form's input filter. The input filter (and the validator chain for each element) is what determines the error messages.

Comment: Dumb question but have you prepared your form ?

Comment: @Hooli You mean [`$form->prepare()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/Form.php#L197)? Yes, I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to detect the validation error(-s) without to debug every (sub-sub-sub-)fieldset and every (sub-sub-sub-)element. It's simple [`$form->getMessages()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/Fieldset.php#L325). Or alternatively [`$this->FormElementErrors($form)`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/View/Helper/FormElementErrors.php) in the view script.

Did I know about this methods before? Sure, I did. But I was unconcerned about the manner, how it works, and the property `messages` led me astray:

When I got validation issues, I set a breakpoint somewhere after the `Zend\Form#isValid()` call and saw then in Xdebug, that `Zend\Form#messages` property was empty. And I was surprised about it, because a property "messages" suggests, that it will contain (validation error) messages. This logic applies to [in `Element`s](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/Element.php#L47) -- and a `Form` actually *is an* `Element` (since `Form` `extends` `Fieldset` `extends` `Element`).